# When one radio group value is 'yes', set second to 'no' and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<div id="first">
  <input type="radio" name="one" value="yes" />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="one" value="no"  />No
</div>

<div id="second">
  <input type="radio" name="two" value="yes" />Yes
  <input type="radio" name="two" value="no"  />No
</div>
```

What I need is when in first div radio 'Yes' is checked then the other radio 'No' in second div should be automatically checked and vice versa. Also, when 'No' in one div then 'Yes' in other. How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Note that IDs have to be **unique**.

Comment: You cant have 2 elements with the same `id`

Comment: Ok, i deleted IDs, thats not important. Will be class when in function

Comment: Try to "get" one value first and put the code up. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of the buttons is selected, find all others with the "opposite" value, excluding the one with the same name.

Example:

```
var $radios = $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    var value = this.value === 'yes' ? 'no' : 'yes';
    $radios.filter('[value=' + value + ']:not([name=' + this.name + '])')
        .prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jEFk/)

Comment: This is great. I have just one more question. How to select just those two radio groups. Because I have more radios in that form with yes/no? Can I put them in one div with ID and select like $('#divid input[type=radio]') ?

Comment: @Yesian_ add a class to the two div containing the inputs, and use the selector `$(".className input[type=radio]")`. see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3jEFk/1/

Comment: @Yesian_: Yes, putting them in the same div with an ID would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also use the `.index()` method:

```
var $elems = $('div').find('input').change(function() {
    $elems.not(this.parentNode)
          .find('input')
          .not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')')
          .prop('checked', true);
}).end();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dYvCq/

Comment: Hey, I am just about to find out, why whithout the `end()` the function doesn't run once. To my understanding it would be only needed to make succeeding calls working!?!

Comment: @dollarvar: Without `.end` `$elems` would contain the `input` elements, not the `div` elements, and `$elems.not(this.parentNode).find('input')` wouldn't work anymore, because the `input` elements don't *contain* other `input` elements.

Comment: @FelixKling Damn, the whole `change` handler is then attached to `input`. :D Thanks! (Right?...)

Comment: @dollarvar: Well yeah, because of `.find('input')`.

Comment: @FelixKling No, yeah, well, I thought the other `.find('input')`, I would have done it like this http://jsfiddle.net/dYvCq/1/ and the whole `var $elem =` caching is new to me. ;)